# Dockerfile - get, modify and set env variable

Tags: dockerfile, environment-variables

probably really simple question, but I cannot find a solution.
I have some env variable what stores some version number.
At this moment it's just 11.1.1.
I need to modify it to get 11.1 and save to env ABC_VER.
So it's possible to do it after building my container like below:

```
export ABC=$(echo $ABC_VERSION | head -c 4)
```

I was trying to do the same in my dockerfile:

```
ENV ABC_VER $(echo $ABC_VERSION | head -c 4)
```

But after building and running echo $ABC_VER I got:

```
$(echo 11.1.1 | head -c 4)
```

instead of 11.1

Not sure, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker's `ENV` instruction is a bit limited in this sense. As far as I know, the most advanced thing you can do is [environment replacement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement), but that won't be of much help here.

I can think of two low-hanging options:

1. Use `RUN` to evaluate the expression you're using and appending an `export` instruction with the result to the appropriate shell startup script (e.g., `/etc/profile` (or preferably a separate file under `/etc/profile.d`))
2. Use `ARG MYARG` in the `Dockerfile` and provide the correctly formatted version as a `--build-arg` and use `ENV ABC_VER=${MYARG}`.